# Understanding the statements of Theorem 5.5 and Lemmas 5.6, 5.7 and 5.8 from a French paper by Yves Guivarc’h and Émile Le Page

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, markov-chains, random-walks

I would like to understand the statement and the proof Theorem 5.5 just for the special case when $X$ is a single point from the paper “Simplicité de spectres de Lyapounov et propriété d’isolation spectrale pour une famille d’opérateurs de transfert sur l’espace projectif” by Yves Guivarc’h and Émile Le Page. The paper is in French and I do not know French. I will paste snippets from the paper and my interpretation in English. I would like to know if the translation I came upon with is correct or not. I would like to thank you for taking the time to read through and for the help.

The following is the definition of condition-IP which appears as Definition 5.4 in the paper:[image]

My translation of it is as follows ( I restrict myself to the case when a group $\Gamma$ is acting on $Z$ continuously) :
Let $Z$ be a compact metric space and $\Gamma\curvearrowright Z$ continuously, denoted by $\alpha$. We view $\Gamma\subset C(Z,Z)$ in this way; each $g\in\Gamma$ induces a map $\phi_g: Z\to Z$ defined by $\phi_g(z)=\alpha(g)z$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a collection of proper closed subsets of $Z$. We say that $(\Gamma,\mathcal{D})$ has Condition (I-P) if the following holds:

(A) For any sequence $f_n\in\Gamma$, we can find $D\in\mathcal{D}$ and a subsequence of $f_n$ converging uniformly to a function $f$ on compact subsets of $Z\setminus D$.

(B) $\Gamma\curvearrowright Z$ is strongly proximal.

(C) For $D\in \mathcal{D}$ and $c\in D$, there exists $g\in \Gamma$ such that $gc\not\in D$.

Theorem 5.5 appears in the paper as follows:
[image]

Since I am interested in the special case when $X$ is just one point, I arrived at the following translation.

Let $Y$ be a compact metrizable $\Gamma$-space. Let $\mu\in\text{Prob}(\Gamma)$ be such that $\text{Supp}(\mu)$ generates $\Gamma$ as a semigroup. Let $\nu\in\text{Prob}_{\mu}(Y)$. Assume that $(\Gamma,Y)$ satisfies Condition-IP. Then, for $\mathbb{P}_{\mu}$-a.e $\omega\in\Omega$, the limit $\lim_n\omega^n\nu=\lim_n\omega_1\omega_2\ldots\omega_n\nu$ exists and is equal to $\delta_{y(\omega)}$ for some $y(\omega)\in Y$.

In order to prove the above theorem, the following Lemmas have been used.
[image]

My translation: Note that $X$ is a single point for me. For $(\omega,\eta)\in\Omega\times\Omega$ and $r,n\in\mathbb{N}$, we set
$$f_n(\omega)=\omega^n\nu, f_n^r(\omega,\eta)=\omega^n\eta^r\nu,$$
where $\omega^n=\omega_1\omega_2\ldots\omega_n$ and $\eta^r=\eta_1\eta_2\ldots\eta_r$. Then, $(\omega,\eta)\in\Omega\times\Omega$ such that for all $r$, the sequence $f_n(\omega)$ and $f_n^r(\omega,\eta)$ converge and have the same limit, is of $\mathbb{P}_{\mu}$- measure $1$.

[image]

My translation: Let $Z$ be a compact metric space, $\nu_n$ a sequence of probabilities on $Z$, vaguely converging to $\nu$. Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous mappings from $Z$ to $Z$ converging uniformly to $f$. Then, the sequence of probabilities $\left(f_n\right)_*\nu_n$ converges vaguely to $f_*\nu$.

[image]

My translation: Let $\Omega'\subset\Omega$ be a co-null set. Let $M$ be a compact subset of $\text{Prob}(Y)$ in variation norm and $D\in\mathcal{D}$. Then, there exists $c\not\in D$ and a sequence $\eta_k\in\Omega'$ such that $\lim_k(\eta_k)^k\rho=\delta_c$ for all $\rho\in M$.

Thanking you for the help.